# Logout with Firebase not working after navigating to a particular screen

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Logout works fine from the home screen and even when navigating to other screens and then returning to the home screen to logout, however, when starting the assessment from the home screen which takes you to 'assessment_list' and you return to the home screen, logout doesn't work. How would I fix this?

Home Screen

```
actions: [
              ...
                items: [
                  DropdownMenuItem(
                    child: Container(
                      child: Row(
                        children: [
                          const Icon(Icons.exit_to_app),
                          const Text('Logout'),
                          const SizedBox(width: 8),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    value: 'logout',
                  ),
                ],
                onChanged: (itemIdentifier) {
                  if (itemIdentifier == 'logout') {
                    FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
                  }
...

                  RaisedButton(
                  child: Text(
                    'Start Assessment'
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    navigateToAssessmentList(context);
                  },
                ),

    ...

Future navigateToAssessmentList(context) async {
  Navigator.push(
      context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => AssessmentList()));
}
```

assessment_list

```
 child: RaisedButton(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                color: const Color(0xfff4f4f4),
                child: Text(
                  'Back To Home',
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => BottomNavBarController()));
                }),
```

Comment: Can you replace `Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => BottomNavBarController()));` with `Navigator.pop(context)` and try again?

Comment: @SanjaySharma Thanks Sanjay that's brilliant, it's worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are pushing the same page again in the stack. Please replace the following line

```dart
Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
    builder: (context) => BottomNavBarController()));
```

with this

```dart
Navigator.pop(context)
```